# Dynamic element with "use" on anonymous function

Tags: php

I want to know if it is possible to create a function who use differents elements / variables with "use" on anonymous function.

For exemple I have this kind of script :

```
$loadScript = function($src) use ($var1, $var2, $var3)
{
   ob_start();
   include($src);
   $result = json_decode(ob_get_clean(),true);
   return $result;
};
$result = $loadScript();
```

And I want to create a function with that script who can permit to use dynamic variable for `use` like this :

```
$src = 'src/...';
$arrayOfUseVars = array($var1,$var2,$var3,...);
function loadScript($src, $arrayOfUseVars)
{
    function($src) use ($arrayOfUseVars)
    {
       ob_start();
       include($src);
       $result = json_decode(ob_get_clean(),true);
       return $result;
    };
}
```

I don't know if it is possible with an array of vars ($arrayOfUseVars) or another methods who can permit to add one or multiple vars dynamically ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, ...) ?

Thanks

Comment: You won’t get any actually named variables this way, but you should be able to access the value you put into the array inside the function same as always - `$arrayOfUseVars[0]`, `$arrayOfUseVars[1]` etc. You could of course also use an associative array with named keys, that might help differentiate between the different possible values a bit better.

Comment: You can also look at this https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I want to call my function "loadScript()" sometimes with 1 vars for the "use" and sometimes with 5 vars or more for the "use", and I don't know if it is possible to do that (it's why I have put the array for the exemple (but I know that it's not possible with the array) but I search another way to do that, if it's possible of course.

Comment: If you want to have the variable available to the included files in their original variable name, then this is impossible.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks it's a good idea, but I have try and "...$myvars" return an array and I can't use it in a second time in the anonymous function with "use", I think there are no way to do this :/

Comment: @KoalaYeung, Yes it's that I want, and it's working with my first exemple (when I put manually all the variable that I need in "use"), but it's not working when I try to create a function who can simplify that way/sript with dynamic "$vars" for "use".

Comment: Why do you insist on using `use`?  Just pass it in as an optional argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass in named variable directly by function call. But you can, however, declare named variables with assoc array.

```php
<?php

$src = 'src/...';
$arrayOfUseVars = array(
  'var1' => $var1,
  'var2' => $var2,
  'var3' => $var3,
);

function loadScript($src, $arrayOfUseVars)
{
    function($src) use ($arrayOfUseVars)
    {
       foreach ($arrayOfUseVars as $_name => $_value) {
         $$_name = $_value;
       }
       ob_start();
       include($src);
       $result = json_decode(ob_get_clean(),true);
       return $result;
    };
}
```

#### Update

Just learn some new tricks. You can rewrite the above code with [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) and [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php). This prevent the name collision with the `$_name` and `$_value` variables in the loop:

```php
<?php

function loadScript($src, $arrayOfUseVars)
{
    function($src) use ($arrayOfUseVars)
    {
       // Note: Use EXTR_SKIP flag to skip creating
       // variable if the named variable exists
       extract($arrayOfUseVars, EXTR_SKIP);
       ob_start();
       include($src);
       $result = json_decode(ob_get_clean(),true);
       return $result;
    };
}

// use compact to pack $var1, $var2 and $var3 into an assoc array
// and send to loadScript for extract
loadScript('src/...', compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3'));
```

Comment: Thanks it was the solution for me, the foreach create again the variable that I want to keep inside the function like "use".
Just the anonymous function is not required with this method ( use ($arrayOfUseVars)  )  so I have simplify my function

Comment: Just learn today that you can declare your `$arrayOfUseVars` with [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php): `$arrayOfUseVars = compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3');`. Seems neat :-)

Comment: Great is perfect with compact, I doesn't know this function, thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KoalaYeung for this answer who work for me, here my final code who can keep variables I want inside the function (like the usage of "use") :

```
function loadScript($src, $arrayOfUseVars = array())
{
    foreach($arrayOfUseVars as $name => $value)
    {
        ${$name} = $value;
    }
    ob_start();
    include($src);
    return json_decode(ob_get_clean(),true);
}
loadScript('src/...', compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3'));
```